# Checkbox Issue with IE8 using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this code

```
 $('#Submit').click(function(event) {
            var checked = $('.inputchbox'); ......IE8
            var ids= checked.map(function() {
                return $(this).val();
            }).get().join(',');
             alert(ids);
        });
```

This Code return all the values which is there for Checkboxbox (.inputchbox is class for the checkbox)

but If I give somethign like this

```
var checked = $('.inputchbox input:checkbox:checked');
or
var checked = $('.inputchbox input[type=checkbox]:checked');
or
var checked = $('.inputchbox input[name=chk]:checked');
or 
var checked = $('.inputchbox').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked');
```

if i am giving like this nothing is working for me I am not getting the result in IE8?

```
 var checked = $('.inputchbox'); .....this is working but I am getting the checkboxes ids its doesnot checking wheather its checked or not..
```

I need to get only checked chekcbox id's

thanks

Comment: Is the `.inputchbox` element the same as the checkbox, or is it a parent of the checkbox as your code implies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
var checked = $('.inputchbox:checked');
```

?
The problem with your snippets is that the space you're using is [the descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) and will look *down* into the DOM. The `.find()` method does the same. g.d.d.c was correct in replying that `.filter()` instead of `.find()` should work equally well (but a marginal amount slower):

```
var checked = $('.inputchbox').filter(':checked');
```

Comment: His last snippet does not do the same thing AFAIK.  If his checkboxes have classes, then `$('.inputchbox').find()` will return children of his checkbox (not likely to exist).  He could also probably use `$('.inputchbox').filter(':checked')` to get there.

Comment: Thanks, you're absolutely right. I should RTFM (RTFApiDocumentation in this case)

Comment: Your first solution is better than the one with `.filter()`. Why retrieve more elements than you need, only to filter some out? (Assuming the class is on the input element.)

Comment: Maybe I should change my name - M is my initial, van belongs to my surname :) But I only included it to show there's also something very similar to the `.find()` solution, except for the final four letters. I also warned him that it's slower.

Answer (score 0):

When you include a space in your selector it implies children.  If you want to get by class with attributes you need to do something like this:  `$('.inputchbox:checked')`

Answer (score 0):

A space in a selectors indicates an [ancestor-descendant relationship](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/), i.e. `.inputchbox` is an ancestor of your checkbox, which from your other example, seems incorrect.

Try:

```
$('input.inputchbox:checkbox:checked');
```

Etc.